# How to switch from Debian to Ubuntu because of Graphics and Microphone issues in Debian Jessie

Tags: gnome, system-installation, 15.10, debian

I've been using Ubuntu from quite some time (my first Linux distro and they sent installation CDs free of cost to my doorstep years ago. :)

Ubuntu's switch to Unity started my declination of liking towards Ubuntu, though I continued using Ubuntu with GNOME. Recently when I purchased a new notebook (Lenovo B40-70) I decided to install Debian Jessie, however I have some issues with the built-in microphone not producing any useful sound and none of the solutions posted on Q&A boards or Skype forums helped me. Additionally, the video playback is choppy when I watch HD or even non-HD videos on YouTube or VLC.

I never faced such issues in Ubuntu because I switched to proprietary drivers when I had problems with display (on my old HP Pavilion G6). Therefore I'm considering switching to Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, and my question is twofold.

1. Will there be similar issues in Ubuntu GNOME - display and microphone? It would be kind of you to share your suggestions.
2. I have huge data on my /home which I mounted on a separate partition and I do not have an external disk at present to store a backup. What precautionary steps do I have to take in order to get Ubuntu installed without wiping my data?

Comment: Create an Ubuntu live USB / DVD, boot it, and see if it works. Ubuntu in general tends to be more stable than Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of doing the same thing and switching to Ubuntu 16.04 for pretty much the same reasons. I haven't done so yet, so I cannot comment on the first part of your question.

With regard to your lack of an external backup, it should not be a problem. I'm assuming you know your way around /etc/fstab, given what you've set up. Ubunt, as with most modern Linux variants, allows flexible use of existing partitions. All you really need to do is make sure the partition containing /home is **not** touched during the install. You'll be asked how you wish to partition your hard drive. You should choose "custom". Then simply ensure that the new install doesn't touch the partition with your data. Afterward you can mount your old partition, though I would avoid mounting it as /home, since the new /home will have a number of invisible files required by your new O/S. You might try mounting it as a subdirectory of your new /home.